# Lock screen triggers application lifecycle events of different activity

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, lockscreen

When I receive a Push message in a service that extends FirebaseMessagingService and I start an Activity in this class, then the following lifecycle events / methods get executed:

- Push Message starts VideoRingingActivity
- Start VideoRingingActivity
- onCreate
- disableLockScreen
- The screen switches from black to the lock screen,
  so it doesn't show the VideoRingingActivity
- onStart
- onResume
- onPause
- onStop
- Now the actual VideoRingingActivity is shown? I was expecting
  this to come up after setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_ringing)
- onRestart
- onStart
- onResume

I have developed below work-around solution where I add a boolean, to determine if the screen is on / off. But this is hacky and when the screen is on in Lock mode then it doesn't work.

Because when the screen is not turned off and MainActivity is shown, and the push message is received, then the behaviour is default Lifecycle behaviour and thus correct. Here is the same flow when the screen is turned on and MainActivity is shown:

- onCreate
- onStart
- onResume

This is correct and to be expected.

```
class VideoRingingActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (ViewUtils.isScreenActive(activity)) {
            screenIsNotLocked = true
        }
        ViewUtils.disableLockScreen(this)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_video_ringing)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (screenIsNotLocked) {
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (screenIsNotLocked) {
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (screenIsNotLocked) {
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (screenIsNotLocked) {
        }
        screenIsNotLocked = true
    }
}

open class ViewUtils {

    @JvmStatic
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    fun disableLockScreen(activity: Activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            activity.setShowWhenLocked(true)
            activity.setTurnScreenOn(true)
        }
        val lock = (activity.getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager).newKeyguardLock(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE)
        val powerManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        val wake = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP or PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "BusSnoozeAlarm")

        lock.disableKeyguard()
        wake.acquire(TIMEOUT)

        activity.window.addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON)
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    fun isScreenActive(context: Context): Boolean {
        val powerManager = context.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            return powerManager.isInteractive
        } else {
            return powerManager.isScreenOn
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** There is another SO thread that has a similar problem, but the solution is outdated and doesn't account for the corner case when the screen is active in lock screen mode:

[OnPause and OnStop() called immediately after starting activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369909/onpause-and-onstop-called-immediately-after-starting-activity/25474853#25474853)

[Why the onPause method is called immediately after onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345282/why-the-onpause-method-is-called-immediately-after-oncreate/14053686#14053686)

Comment: Rather than `onCreate()`, try your conditions in `onStart()` will better help you determine whether activity is displayed or not.